# Iterating Over Elements and Sub Elements With lxml

Tags: python, lxml

This one is for legitimate `lxml` gurus. I have a web scraping application where I want to iterate over a number of `div.content` (content is the class) tags on a website. Once in a div.content tag, I want to see if there are any `<a>` tags that are the children of `<h3>` elements. This seems relatively simple by just trying to create a list using `XPath` from the div.cont tag, i.e.,

```
linkList = tree.xpath('div[contains(@class,"cont")]//h3//a')
```

The problem is, I then want to create a `tuple` that contains the link from the div.content box as well as the text from the paragraph element of the same div.content box. I could obviously iterate over the whole document and store all of the paragraph text as well as all of the links, but I wouldn't have any real way of matching the appropriate paragraphs to the `<a>` tags.

lxml's `Element.iter()` function could ALMOST achieve this by iterating over all of the `div.cont` elements, ignoring those without `<a>` tags, and pairing up the `paragraph/a` combos, but unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any option for iterating over class names, only tag names, with that method.

Edit: here's an extremely stripped down version of the HTML I want to parse:

```
<body>
<div class="cont">
    <h1>Random Text</h1>
    <p>The text I want to obtain</p>
    <h3><a href="somelink">The link I want to obtain</a></h3>
</div>
</body>
```

There are a number of div.conts like this that I want to work with -- most of them have far more elements than this, but this is just a sketch to give you an idea of what I'm working with.

Comment: can you post some sample HTML?

Comment: okay, just posted a rough example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use a less specific XPath expression:

```
for matchingdiv in tree.xpath('div[contains(@class,"cont")]'):
    # skip those without a h3 > a setup.
    link = matchingdiv.xpath('.//h3//a')
    if not link:
        continue

    # grab the `p` text and of course the link.
```

You could expand this (be ambitious) and select for the `h3` > `a` tags, then go to the `div.cont` ancestor (based off [XPath query with descendant and descendant text() predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920957/xpath-query-with-descendant-and-descendant-text-predicates)):

```
for matchingdiv in tree.xpath('.//h3//a/ancestor::*[self::div[contains(@class,"cont")]]'):
    # no need to skip anymore, this is a div.cont with h3 and a contained
    link = matchingdiv.xpath('.//h3//a')

    # grab the `p` text and of course the link
```

but since you need to then scan for the link anyway that doesn't actually buy you anything.

Comment: This looks solid. Would it still work if <h3> weren't an immediate child of class.cont? For instance, if <h3> were contained within a wrapper like <div class="downloads"> or something?

Comment: @user1427661: That's what the `.//` prefix does; search for a descendant of the current element (not just a child).